# Rails with Sunspot - How do I output the facet results?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot

I'm extremely new to Ruby, Rails and Sunspot, let alone Solr! So, excuse me if this all seems a bit 'dumb'.

I have the following setup.

**Model**

```
class Pin < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :user
    has_many :replies
    has_one :type

    validates :user_id, presence: true
    validates :type_id, presence: true
    validates :title, presence: true
    validates :description, presence: true

    searchable do

        text :title, :boost => 5
        text :description
        integer :type_id

    end

end
```

**Controller**

```
def index

@search = Pin.search do

    fulltext params[:keywords]
    facet :type_id

end

@pins = @search.results

end
```

**View**

```
<% @search.facet(:type_id).rows.each do |facet| %>
            <%= puts "Type #{facet.value} has #{facet.count} pins!" %>
        <% end %>
```

But when I try to view this on the page, all I get is:

```
[<Sunspot::Search::FacetRow:1 (6)>, <Sunspot::Search::FacetRow:2 (6)>]
```

Am I missing something here?

I want to be able to output the available types for each pin.

Thanks!
Mikey

**UPDATE:**

So, it turns out I should be doing this in my view:

```
<% @search.facet(:type_id).rows.each do |facet| %>
<%= facet.value %>
<% end %>
```

This now outputs the type ID from the pin. Great! However, if this ID is joined to another table, where the type TITLE is also held, how can I grab that with the facet??

So, all pins have a type id...that is related to a types table. My models are set up correctly but I could not work out how to do this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is actually an ERB issue

When you do:

```
<%= @search.facet(:type_id).rows.each do |facet| %>
```

You are outputting the result of

```
@search.facet(:type_id).rows.each do |facet|
```

Replace it with this instead

```
<% @search.facet(:type_id).rows.each do |facet| %>
```

(Notice the lack of '=')

Comment: That additional '=' was actually a typo. The issue still stands. I need to grab the title, but it only returns the objects ID. I can work with this and have a work-around but it seems a bit dirty.